# Trying to use Hexagon Delegate for a tflite project

Tags: tensorflow-lite, hexagon-dsp

I have integrated the hexagon delegate in a sample `TensorFlow Lite Image Classification` app. It was running successfully until a couple of days ago. Now, the app crashes when I try to inference using the hexagon delegate.

From the logs, I see the following error:

```
*remote_handle_open_domain: dynamic loading failed for file:///libhexagon_nn_skel_v66.so?hexagon_nn_domains_skel_handle_invoke&_modver=1.0&_dom=cdsp on domain 3 (dlerror segment 0 failed signature verification (0xF4 B) for libhexagon_nn_s*"
```

This is not a target specific issue because the old apk's still work with Hexagon DSP. All the fresh builds result in the crashing of the app when Hexagon is invoked.

Comment: Can you file a github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?assignees=&labels=type%3Aothers&template=50-other-issues.md)
Please include any reproduce steps, so that the team can debug this. I assume from your answer, you didn't change any of the libraries, just pulled the newer nightly, correct ?

Comment: That's right. I pull the nightly version for the hexagon library. I'll also try to raise a github issue. I am new to TensorFlow so thought I might find a quick fix here. Thanks!